# A continuous mapping on a ball, that does not change the boundary

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $B$ be an $n$-dimensional ball, and let $f$ be a continuous mapping from $B$ to itself, such that $f(x)=x$ for all $x$ on the boundary of $B$.

Intuitively, $f$ represents a "stretching" of $B$ such that its boundary remains fixed.

Is such a function $f$ necessarily a bijection?

Comment: What did you try? Did you consider 1d case?

Comment: It must be onto, since if not then one would easily construct a continuous retraction from the ball onto boundary which (as it is well known) is not possible.

Comment: A picture in the one dimensional case should convince you that this is very, very false.

Comment: A much more fun question is, is the function necessarily surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 1D case, for a ball of radius 1 around 0, what about $\max(0, 2|x|-1) \operatorname{sign}(x)$?

I think you could extend the same idea to higher dimensions -- rather than sign, you'd have a unit vector for direction, and transform the magnitude of the input.